# Classic Asp - Server.Tranfer to parent path - is it possible

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have an classic asp application where I would like to use Server.Transfer(path) so that the path points to asp-file that locates in the parent directory. I can only have Server.Transfer work for now only for asp-files that are either in the same directory as the calling asp-page or in child directories (using Server.Transfer("routine.asp") or Server.Transfer("./childfol/routine.asp")). I have been trying to find examples how to define path to asp files that are in parent folders - so far without any success, I only get the error: "0x80004005 - Server object: 006~ASP 0230~Server.Transfer Error~The call to Server.Transfer failed while loading the page."

Is it possible to use parents paths with Server.Transfer? - And if so how to define path. I have been trying many variations like: Server.Transfer("../parentpath/routine.asp")

And note that I have enabled parent paths in IIS!

Comment: Did you try `Server.Transfer "/parentpath/routine.asp"`?

Comment: What you suggested, i.e. "/parentpath/routine.asp" works if I try with test files outside of my project but not within the actual project code. The reason might be that other factors in actual project code can somehow prevent the parent-path finding. The calling page itself is first the target for http-404-error redirecting via web.config and yet there is also in the cases of http methods other than GET, the extra http 307 redirecting from the calling page back to the same calling page. Maybe the situation gets too complex for IIS to find the parent path anymore. I do not know really.

Comment: Here are actual absolute paths for you to reckon: In the verbs.asp-file I have this and it does not work: D:\ClassicAsp\Restful\restApp\src\config\dependencies\core\verbs.asp
Server.Transfer("/dependencies/routine.asp").
And this is the absolute path of routine.asp -file
D:\ClassicAsp\Restful\restApp\src\config\dependencies\routine.asp

Comment: I ended refactoring a bit my project and now I can transfer to the same directory and it works fine.